# using date picker how to disable the range date in angular6?

Tags: html, datepicker, angular6, ng-bootstrap

There are 2 entities: one is *holiday* another is *microplan*. In *holiday* there are 2 fields. One for start date and another for end date. In *microplan* there is just one field, microplan start date. My question is I just want to disable the date in microplan start date field, which date I select in *holdiay* those dates are disabe in microplan start date. In my case dates are not disabled in calendar: [image: Calendar]]

*microplan.html*

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="field_microplanStartDate">Microplan Start Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="field_microplanStartDate" [disabled]="isHoliday" type="text" class="form-control" name="microplanStartDate" ngbDatepicker  #microplanStartDateDp="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="microplan.microplanStartDate"
        />
        <span class="input-group-append">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="microplanStartDateDp.toggle()">
                <fa-icon [icon]="'calendar-alt'"></fa-icon>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

*microplan.ts*

```
private getIsHoliday(holidays) {
    for (let i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
        const today = new Date();
        const date1 = new Date(holidays[i].startDate._i);
        const date2 = new Date(holidays[i].endDate._i);
        const day1 = date1.getFullYear() + '' + this.getIfLess(date1.getMonth()) + '' + this.getIfLess(date1.getDate());
        const day2 = date2.getFullYear() + '' + this.getIfLess(date2.getMonth()) + '' + this.getIfLess(date2.getDate());
        const todayDate = today.getFullYear() + '' + this.getIfLess(today.getMonth()) + '' + this.getIfLess(today.getDate());
        if (todayDate >= day1) {
            if (todayDate <= day2) {
                this.isHoliday = true;
            }
        }
    }
}


private getIfLess(date) {
    if (date <= 9) {
        return '0' + date;
    } else {
        return date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using ngbDatepicker, as I saw in the html code. It does have a date disabling feature. You can look into this [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#limiting-dates).

```js
// disable the 13th of each month
const isDisabled = (date: NgbDate, current: {
  month: number
}) => day.date === 13;
```

```html
<ngb-datepicker [minDate]="{year: 2010, month: 1, day: 1}" [maxDate]="{year: 2048, month: 12, day: 31}" [markDisabled]="isDisabled">
</ngb-datepicker>
```

This should help you, just take the holiday date and as soon as the user inserts the holiday date set it to microplan date. It will disable automatically. Hope it helps.